# Local Extrema and Global Extrema

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

When we have a convex function we know that a local minimum is a global minimum, and similarly for a concave function.  What are some other situations where finding local extrema can yield global extrema with certainty?  Are they common?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two common classes of functions with similar relation between local and global are [quasiconvex functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) and their counterparts, quasiconcave functions.

Here, quasiconvexity is understood as the property that the set $\{x:\phi(x)< a\}$ is convex for every $a$. (In PDE theory this term has a different meaning).  The composition of a convex function and an increasing function is quasiconvex.

Wikipedia gives a few examples such as this one, which looks like a translate of $\sqrt{|x|}$.

[image: quasiconcave function]